# Method not found: 'Void Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore..ctor(System.String)'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been stuck at this for days now. I copied the exact codes from google api samples to upload files to Google Drive. Here is the code

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
           new ClientSecrets
           {
               ClientId = ClientId,
               ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
           },
           new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore("MyStore")).Result;
```

But it would throw an exception at runtime: Method not found: 'Void Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore..ctor(System.String)'. I already added the necessary Google Api dlls.

Or if anyone could suggest a better code for uploading files to Google Drive in a website which implements Server-Side Authorization. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I changed my code to this

```
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "1/6hnki1x0xOMU4tr5YXNsLgutzbTcRK1M-QOTEuRVxL4" }; 
               var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = ClientId,
                        ClientSecret = ClientSecret
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { 
                        DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile
                    }
                }), "user", token);
```

But it also throws an exception: Method not found: 'Void Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow..ctor(Initializer). Is the problem with the dlls?

Comment: Is this throwing an exception at runtime, or are you getting a compile error?

Comment: I dont know why you have this exception exactly but I think you should at least have something like that : UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...); Or if you dont want to execute your method async something like that : var task = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...); var cred = task.Wait(); Can you try ? Btw, to don't execute async is not a good thing since it will block the main thread of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. Can I do that with VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug in  `v1.8.2 of Google APIs Client Library`. Try using [v1.8.1 using nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/1.8.1)
with .NET framework 4.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts as well, but the downgrade worked. I hope it all gets sorted out soon.

Comment: squid808m,user3732193 and Antony Thomas,

Answer (score 1):

It's really weird. All our samples are using the new library (1.8.2), and they work. Maybe it is related to VS2010, or not installing one of the latest .NET 4 patches? (Make sure .NET Framework 4.0 update KB2468871 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) is installed.

The fact that samples run successfully implies that our environment is different. I'm using VS 2012 on Windows 8. What do you use?

Feel free to open a new issue in our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list), and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done to resolve the issue :

```
public UserCredential GetRefreshToken(string refreshToken, string clientID, string clientSecret, string[] scopes)
{
    TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse
    {
        RefreshToken = refreshToken
    };

    IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new AuthorizationCodeFlow(new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer(Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleAuthConsts.AuthorizationUrl, Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleAuthConsts.TokenUrl)
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientID,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        Scopes = scopes
    });

    UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, "me", token);
    try
    {
        bool success = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using Visual Studio 2013 + Update 3 on win 8.1
.NET 4.5 was set as the Target Framework of my Console Project (this is selected by default).
The issue was fixed by removing every reference to the google apis. 
Then switching the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4" (Select project from solution explorer, right click -> Properties -> Application Page -> Target Framework dropdown)
Then installing apis with nuget in the following order:

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
```

Comment: To bad I need features of .NET 4.5. :(