# Google Calendar V3 API working with .NET 4.0, but not .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've spent many hours trying to get the sample at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate to work on a Console application.

After countless trial and error, I found out that it works absolutely fine if used with .NET Framework 4.0, but throws an exception `"Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore..ctor(System.String)'."` if used within 4.5.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? If so, is there a viable fix? (There's no way I can downgrade an entire application to 4.0, I'm afraid)

Comment: Put it in its own 4.0 DLL, and call it from your main program.

Comment: I did try that. Unfortunately, same exception.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174657/method-not-found-void-google-apis-util-store-filedatastore-ctorsystem-string